# Spring 3.2.1 + hibernate-core 4.2.0: merge() not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm starting to learn Spring for web development using springapp example. Now, I'm trying to increase the price of every product in a list (retrieved from a database) and then save back to the DB with the new prices. It can retrieve the product list but merge doesn't do anything. I added .flush() to the code and it gave an ugly exception (just as soon as the application starts).

This is the exception thrown as soon as application starts (before invoking method calling .flush()):

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:993)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366)
at $Proxy18.flush(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
at $Proxy18.flush(Unknown Source)
at org.springtest.mavenspringapp.repository.JPAProductDao.saveProduct(JPAProductDao.java:34)
at org.springtest.mavenspringapp.service.SimpleProductManager.increasePrice(SimpleProductManager.java:35)
at org.springtest.mavenspringapp.web.PriceIncreaseFormController.onSubmit(PriceIncreaseFormController.java:38)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is once I increase each product's price and invoke .merge() followed by .flush():

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:993)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366)
$Proxy18.flush(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:241)
$Proxy18.flush(Unknown Source)
org.springtest.mavenspringapp.repository.JPAProductDao.saveProduct(JPAProductDao.java:34)
org.springtest.mavenspringapp.service.SimpleProductManager.increasePrice(SimpleProductManager.java:35)
org.springtest.mavenspringapp.web.PriceIncreaseFormController.onSubmit(PriceIncreaseFormController.java:38)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:920)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:801)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
```

This is ProductDao:

```
@Repository(value = "productDao")
public class JPAProductDao implements ProductDao {

    private EntityManager em = null;

    /*
     * Sets the entity manager.
     */
    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Product> getProductList() {
        return em.createQuery("select p from Product p").getResultList();
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void saveProduct(Product prod) {
        em.merge(prod);
        em.flush();
    }

}
```

This is a method in my controller processing the price increase form:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String onSubmit(@Valid PriceIncrease priceIncrease, BindingResult result)
{
    if (result.hasErrors())
    {
        return "priceincrease";
    }

    int increase = priceIncrease.getPercentage();
    logger.info("Increasing prices by " + increase + "%.");

    productManager.increasePrice(increase);

    return "redirect:/hello.htm";
}
```

ProductManager is a service which is implemented by a class named SimpleProductManager. This class updates each product's price and attempts to save it to the DB through JpaProductDao.

Here's my applicationContext.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- holding properties for database connectivity /-->
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>

    <!-- enabling annotation driven configuration /-->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
      <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
      <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
      <property name="username"  value="${jdbc.username}"/>
      <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaAdapter">
    <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
            <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
    </property>                             
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="springappPU"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jpaAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    p:database="${jpa.database}"
    p:showSql="${jpa.showSql}"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>

    <!-- <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>-->
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springtest.mavenspringapp">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>
    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans 
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springtest.mavenspringapp.repository" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springtest.mavenspringapp.service" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springtest.mavenspringapp.web" />-->

</beans>
```

BTW, I added the .flush method call because someone suggested it here (it was another question about not persisting changes).

Almost forgot, if .flush() is not included products are not updated and not exception is thrown. This is hibernate log output:

```
Hibernate: select product0_.id as id1_0_0_, product0_.description as descript2_0_0_, product0_.price as price3_0_0_ from products product0_ where product0_.id=?
Hibernate: select product0_.id as id1_0_0_, product0_.description as descript2_0_0_, product0_.price as price3_0_0_ from products product0_ where product0_.id=?
Hibernate: select product0_.id as id1_0_, product0_.description as descript2_0_, product0_.price as price3_0_ from products product0_
```

I hope you can help me. Thanks in advanced.

EDIT: I'm posting my web.xml file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <display-name>Mavenspringapp</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mavenspringapp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mavenspringapp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

app-config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="messages"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springtest.mavenspringapp" use-default-filters="false">
        <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
    </context:component-scan>


    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView">
        </property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: Please post your web.xml.

Comment: @M.Deinum I edited my question, i am now including my web.xml file content

Comment: Can you also add **app-config.xml**.

Comment: app-config.xml now included in the question.

Comment: And there is your problem... As already hinted at in my initial answer. You are loading your beans twice once proxied (`ContextLoaderListener` and once unproxied `DispatcherServlet` basically you are rendering all your transaction settings, aop stuff useless). Your `ContextLoaderListener` should scan for everything **BUT** `@Controller` and your `DispatcherServlet` should **ONLY** scan for `@Controller`. (See my modified answer).

Comment: I've made all of the modifications you suggested but still no luck. If .flush() is included, then it throws the transactionRequired Exception. If it isn't, then no exceptions are raised but changes don't persist either. I'll post my new xml files so you can see what I did... As I said, I'm new to Springframework and honestly there are many many parts that made me ask myself "What the heck is this talking about?? I'll just paste it and see how it goes...", so there's a chance that the modifications applied aren't the way they were supposed to be.

Comment: Remove `mode="aspectj"` from your `<tx:annotation-driven />`. As that requires AspectJ load- or compile time weaving and that isn't what you are using. Also you can remove `<context:annotation-driven />` as that is already implied by `<context:component-scan />`. The `@Transactional` annotation should actually be on your `SimpleProductManager` as that is your service layer and thus transactional boundary. The repositories automatically participate in this transaction.

Comment: OMG! Thanks a lot @M.Deinum! I finally got it working! Where can I find more information about this? And by more information I mean a for-dummies level.. I would like to create a web app using spring framework but I need to thouroughly understand this.

Comment: [The spring reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/) is a good start, next to that the [Spring website](http://www.spring.io) has some nice guides/tutorials which you can take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from your stack trace you are loading your beans twice, once by the `ContextLoaderListener` which has correctly transactions defined. And once in the `DispatcherServlet` without transactions. (Your stack trace doesn't show a `TransactionInterceptor` which leads me to believe this).

Make sure that you don't scan for the same components twice (don't duplicate the `<context:component-scan />` elements in both the configuration files.

The problem is the following line in your **app-config.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springtest.mavenspringapp" />
```

This **again** creates new instances of all your beans and doesn't apply transactions to it. AOP is only applied in the same application context the beans are defined in. So basically you have 2 instances of your `JPAProductDao` one (which sits there useless) with transactions and what not applied in the `ApplicationContext` loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` and another one (no transactions applied) in the `ApplicationContext` loaded by your `DispatcherServlet`.

Modify the component-scanning your **applicationContext.xml** to the following

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springtest.mavenspringapp">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```

and in your app-config.xml to the following (note: don't forget the `use-default-filters` attribute!!!!)

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.springtest.mavenspringapp" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />
</context:component-scan>
```

You can also remove the `<context:annotation-config />` that is already implied by the use of `<context:component-scan />`. Saves you another line of xml.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't got a transaction as the exception suggests: `javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress`

You need an overarching transaction as the object you pass to your `saveProduct` method has been detached (it's no longer managed by the entity manager).

Annotate your controller with `@Transactional` and you should be good. Remember after you fetch your object they still need to be managed in order to update them. Also remove the `readOnly = true` when fetching the objects. Furthermore, you don't actually need the `@Transactional` annotation on the repository as in all cases I can think of you would need an overarching transaction, and you don't need a transaction to read from a datasource.

Comment: After \@Controller I added an \@Transactional annotation. But still not persisting.

Comment: Did you remove the @Transactional annotations from your JPAProductDao as well?

Comment: You might also need to declare annotation driven transaction management as follows in your configuration: <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

Comment: Note the mode="aspectj" difference between your configuration

Comment: I noticed the difference so I replaced mine with the declaration you provided. I also removed the \Transactional but it is not working yet.

Comment: Out of interest - did you revert these changes I suggested when accepting the other answer?

Comment: Actually, part of your answer was to annotate my controller instead of my DAO, so I didn't revert changes. Although, the aspectJ part wasn't necessary.

Comment: Mmm... so it seems like a two part answer. The first part being that the controller needed the @Transactional annotation - perhaps mention that as a comment on the accepted answer and give this answer an upvote :)

Comment: I gave your answer an upvote because part of it was included in the solution. As you can see there is a comment, posted by the user who provided the accepted answer, where annotate controllers is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

[documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/transaction.html)

Comment: I added what you suggested but still not persisting

Comment: but did you get same exception with flush?

Comment: Yes, it is the same exception

Comment: your @ transactional is not getting scanned, so i am not sure about the rest of the packages that you have but i suggest to remove everything and leave only <context:component-scan base-package="org.springtest.mavenspringapp" /> (if org.springtest.mavenspringapp is your base package), also I would suggest to use EntityManagerFactory over EntityManager and since you are annotating it with @ PersistenseContext you don't need setter(you can use it same as autowired)